# php: How to foreach a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have been trying for a while but I can't seem to loop through a multi dimensional array.

I have this array:

```
$Work["work_time"] = array();
$Work["break_time"] = array();
$Work["meeting_time"] = array();
$Work["login_time"] = array();
$Work["logout_time"] = array();
$Work["work_date"] = array();
```

Which print_r($Work) outputs this

```
Array
(
    [work_time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.00
            [1] => 3.96
            [2] => 7.75
        )

    [break_time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.00
            [1] => 0.00
            [2] => 1.06
        )

    [meeting_time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.00
            [1] => 0.00
            [2] => 0.00
        )

    [login_time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10:11
            [1] => 08:48
            [2] => 09:09
        )

    [logout_time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00
            [1] => 13:00
            [2] => 17:59
        )

    [work_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2018-04-13
            [1] => 2018-04-16
            [2] => 2018-04-17
        )
)
```

And then I tried to use a foreach loop to loop through it and get the values but it returns nothing..

```
foreach ($Work as $row) {
 echo $row["login_time"];
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: Where does this array come from? Is it input from an HTML form?

Comment: Not a duplicate

Comment: @CharisMoutafidis It may be a duplicate of _something_, but I agree it has nothing to do with sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array you're trying to iterate with your foreach loop is not the same as the array you have. In order to use that loop, your array would need to be like this instead:

```
[
    [
        'work_time' => 0.00,
        'break_time' => 0.00,
        'meeting_time' => 0.00,
        'login_time' => '10:11',
        'logout_time' => '00:00',
        'work_date' => '2018-04-13'
    ],
    [
        'work_time' => 3.96,
        'break_time' => 0.00,
        'meeting_time' => 0.00,
        'login_time' => '08:48',
        'logout_time' => '13:00',
        'work_date' => '2018-04-16'
    ],
    [
        'work_time' => 7.75,
        'break_time' => 1.06,
        'meeting_time' => 0.00,
        'login_time' => '09:09',
        'logout_time' => '17:59',
        'work_date' => '2018-04-17'
    ],
];
```

The array you have looks like the type of input you get if you have an HTML form with multiple rows of inputs with names like this:

```
<input type="text" name="work[work_time][]">
```

If that is the case, you can get an array like the one I showed above instead by switching the keys around and specifying a numeric key for each row:

```
<input type="text" name="work[0][work_time]">
```

Then it will make more sense to access the data as rows. If that's not the case, well, never mind. :)

---

On the other hand, with the array you have, you can just iterate one of the inner arrays directly. For example, if you wanted to show login_time values, it's just

```
foreach ($Work['login_time'] as $login_time) {
    echo $login_time;
}
```

If you need to get corresponding values from the other inner arrays, you can use the key from the array you're iterating to access those as well:

```
foreach ($Work['login_time'] as $key => $login_time) {
    echo 'login time: ' . $login_time . ', work_date: ' . $Work['work_date'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really dont know how many dimensions you are dealing with, a recursive solution is what you need.
Here is my code:

```
$Work["work_time"] = array(1, 2, 3);
$Work["break_time"] = array(4, 5, 6);
$Work["meeting_time"] = array(7, 8, 9);
$Work["login_time"] = array(10, 11, 12);
$Work["logout_time"] = array(13, 14, 15);
$Work["work_date"] = array(16, 17, 18);

function forLoop($array){
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        if(is_array($row)){
            forLoop($row);
        }
        else{
            echo $row;
            echo " ";
        }
    }
}

forLoop($Work);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

You actually need to make a formating or something to make it work the way you want it to.
Edit: forLoop function calls it's self so it will work on any dimension array. Tell me what you think!

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the key you need (login_time), you do not need to iterate the array. You can access it directly as `$Work["login_time"]`.

If you want to iterate `$Work["login_time"]`, you can use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($Work['login_time'] as $row) {
   echo $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably need multiple for loops

```
foreach ($Work as $row) {
   foreach($row as $key => $rs) {
       echo $rs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop completely you would need a 2nd foreach inside the first foreach.  Like This:

```
 foreach ($Work as $row) {
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key - $value";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($dataArray as $innerArray){
   foreach ($innerArray as $key=>$value){
   // here is where you access the array -- $value
   }
}
```